# Object material/color not visible - Only wireframe

Tags: objects, color, wireframe

[image]

I'm a total beginner in Blender and I can't get this object to show any color/material. Once I merged the bottom circle with the plane, the plane lost it's color and now only a wireframe is visible. I have tried to add a material (see above) but it still doesn't show. I also made sure that wireframe mode is turned off. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object has no faces, it just has edges.

[image]

In edit mode select the vertices of your object and press F to fill, and create a face to which you can assign a material.